# How do I create dual dropdown lists in Blazor C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, blazor

I have this code in Block 1 that populates phone numbers from a list. Block 2 is for the "Add Phone Number" button, and Block 3 is for the "Continue" button.

[image: code screenshot]

It's in VB using ASP.NET MVC, but it has to be rewritten in C# using Blazor. The LabelFor control is not available to me, and I do not understand what the Function code `Function(m) m.PhoneNumbers, New With {.class = "pi-item-label"}` is doing.

`PhoneNumbers` is *List*, and `PhoneNumberModel` is here:

```vb
Public Class PhoneNumberModel

    Public Property PhoneNumberID As Long

    Public Property PhoneTypeID As Integer

    Public PhoneTypeName As String

    Public Property PhoneTypeList As List(Of SelectListItem)

    <StringLength(25, ErrorMessage:=StringLengthMaxError),
    Display(Name:="Number"),
    CustomDataAnnotations.PhoneNumber(),
    Required(ErrorMessage:=RequiredError)>
    Public Property DialNumber As String

End Class
```

Whenever it renders, it creates two (2) dropdown lists: one for the phone type and one for the dial number.

[image: page screenshot]

How would I duplicate this in a C# Blazor page?

### Update:

I'm still stuck on this. Nothing I try seems to work.

Here is the VB code in MVC with some highlights as landmarks for the C# code:

[image: vbMVC]

Here is the C# code in Blazor with the same highlighted areas:

[image: csBlazor]

Here is how my output looks with the C# code:

[image: csOutput]

Are there any obvious things that I am doing wrong?

### Solution:

Using the accepted solution below, I was able to get it to work. It took me some time to make it look nice, and below are my results:

[image: final code]

This produced the current output:

[image: final screenshot]

I'm still working to figure out why the [Add] and [Continue] buttons are not on the same line, but that should not take too much longer.

Comment: You're asking too many questions in a single post, we wouldn't get the credit that we deserve after we put in the time that you are requesting to produce a result that you will comprehend. It's not that we can't, it's just that there are limited number of hours in a day. You should consider finding a mentor who can coach you through this.

Comment: Instead of trying to convert the code, try to replicate the outcome without looking at the code. Converting MVC to Blazor line by line is doable but you have to understand a lot about both MVC and Blazor to do it efficiently. You are also asking for a conversion of VB to C# at the same time, there are so many knowledge variables here that make this a really toxic type of question to ask when we don't know you. It's the sort of question that developers and problem solvers would love to assist with, but this platform is not the right place for this type of question.

Comment: Hi @ChrisSchaller. I'm not sure how to ask it differently. I updated my question with more details at the bottom, specifically, what I am trying that is not working. Is there anything else that I can add to help someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the Model in C#

`public class PhoneNumberModel
{
    public long PhoneNumberID { get; set; }
    public int PhoneTypeID { get; set; }
    public string PhoneTypeName { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> PhoneTypeList { get; set; } 

    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "StringLengthMaxError")]
    [Display(Name = "Number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RequiredError")]
    public string DialNumber { get; set; }
}`

In Blazor component you'll need to handle the dropdowns. Blazor does not use LabelFor or similar helpers as in MVC, but you can easily create labels and inputs manually.

```
 @code {
        private List<PhoneNumberModel> phoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumberModel>();
        private List<SelectListItem> phoneTypeOptions = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            // Initialize your PhoneNumbers and PhoneTypeOptions
        }
    
        private void AddPhoneNumber()
        {
            phoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumberModel());
        }
    
        private void Continue()
        {
            // Handle the continue action
        }
    }
    
    @foreach (var phoneNumber in phoneNumbers)
    {
        <div>
            <label>Phone Type</label>
            <select @bind="phoneNumber.PhoneTypeID">
                @foreach (var option in phoneTypeOptions)
                {
                    <option value="@option. Value">@option.Text</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Number</label>
            <input type="text" @bind="phoneNumber.DialNumber" />
        </div>
    }
    
    <button @onclick="AddPhoneNumber">Add Phone Number</button>
    <button @onclick="Continue">Continue</button>
```

Implement the SelectListItem Class

`public class SelectListItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `@Html.LabelFor()` and `@Html.EditorFor()` do not work in blazor. The *"Blazor"* solution is to use components instead of the MVC Html Helper that resolved label and editor templates for types.

> **[ASP.NET Core Blazor forms overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/?view=aspnetcore-8.0)**
> Follow this guide to learn about basic mechanics of edit forms that you get OOTB in Blazor. Many 3rd party libraries have their own form builders or helper components but the `EditForm` has enough to replicate most MVC native forms like the one you have described.

Lets skip past the `@Html.LabelFor` as your workaround will work. Instead we can focus on just the drop down list, as that it the title of your post. There is no peculiarity to *dual* drop downs in this instance, it is simply a form that has multiple drop downs that are mutually exclusive, so lets build 1 drop down list.

In MVC, your equivalent C# code would be `@Html.EditorFor(() => m.PhoneNumbers)`. But this is an instruction to locate the *template* for the *type* of the Property called `PhoneNumbers` on the Model. More than likely you will find the applicable template in a file names something similar to this `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PhoneNumbers.vbhtml` This template is actually just a vertical repeating table of 2 rows, with two columns, the cell in the first column is a drop down list, the second column has a simple text input control. I wouldn't bother creating a specific component for just the phone numbers, even if you want to encapsulate logic like cascading selections or mutual selections (removing previous selected items from the other lists) I would still leave this inline until you understand Blazor components a bit better.

This line that you have attempted will not work:
`<input value="@data.PhoneNumbers" />`
The type of `PhoneNumbers` is a custom type that is not parsable as string and so not natively supported. You will have to implement the template directly.

So how does 1 drop down work in Blazor? Good question, but you have already solved that with your `InputSelect` for State, Country and Citizenship. (the code for none of these you have included in your post)

The only *trick* to this is that you need the list of phone number types to render, each drop down is built from the same list of options, but the value will be saved into different fields on the model.

Hopefully that helps you on your journey, the answers are in both the MVC project your are converting and the existing conversion work you have done. You have not included the relevant code snippets that are needed to produce a definitive example code, but I have confidence that you will figure it out.